# Династия: Немановичи или Неманичи (Сербия)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, ономастика

Иначе: откуда столько упоминаний Немановичей (гуглено)?

У меня:

> Так в XII столетии крепость переживёт свой расцвет, который берёт
>   начало в дни правления Немановичей.

Ничего, что расцвет берёт начало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Так в XII столетии крепость переживёт свой расцвет, **начавшийся в годы правления Неманичей.***

***Неманичи.*** Династия правителей в Сербии во второй половине XII века — 1371 г. Основатель — **великий жупан** Стефан Неманя.

https://info.wikireading.ru/20852

Обычно встречается вариант ***Неманичи***. Вроде бы так: Неманов — Неманович, Неманя — Неманич.

Comment: Тут ещё допвопросец: ***Ничего, что расцвет берёт начало?***

Comment: Мне не очень понравилось, поэтому я исправила. Расцвет обычно начинается. Я посмотрела предложения, в которых используется выражение "берет начало", там оно действительно на месте, "начинается" не подходит. А если можно сказать "начинается", то лучше использовать это слово. https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/брать%20начало

Answer (score 0):

> Откуда столько упоминаний Немановичей?

Дык... По образцу Рюрик - рюриковичи. Но это ошибка. Немановичи - от "Немана", от "Немани" невозможно этимологиски.

*В принципе могло бы быть **Неманевичи/Неманьевичи**. Но - не судьба, закрепился
вариант Неманичи.*

В русском языке есть два суффикса (-ов и -ич), обозначающих принадлежность к роду (-ец и -ль - менее употребительны). В русском до определенного момента разделение было более или менее регулярным - ***"Такойтовы"*** - дети Такойта, ***"Такойтовичи"*** - все потомки. 
Потом система упростилась.

В том или ином виде они существовали во многих славянских, включая сербский. Поэтому "Неманевичи" - не было бы исторический ошибкой. Но закрепился более простой вариант, что определяется еще и конечной гласной. Сравните в русском: Данила - Данилычи, Данииил- Данииловичи.

Вместе с тем огромное количество сербских знатных родов сохраняет -ов- в качестве первого родового суффикса. Войновичи (от "воjн", Лазаровичи, Миятовичи, Черноевичи и т.д.